# Set Tx Power and the wave emit frequency

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter to create my app for android and ios now and I have waste lots of time to find out how to set the Tx Power of beacon and the wave emit frequency, but still can't found out the solution.

Can anyone please assist me to find out the code to set Tx Power and the wave emit frequency or some useful link.